# How to import products form 3 different sites to new magento site?

Tags: magento-1.9

There is a requirement in my new site is that it will show product from 3 different website, not the store but the complete different website.

My Question is how i am gonna achieve it, if i setup a master slave db then there will be problem as there can only be one master in my knowledge.

So how can i achieve it, what should i do to import products and category from 3 different site to my site, and also setup a process so when any of the site updates its products my new site gets updates too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question.

You have to generate a product import CSV file from the 3 different sites and then import them in you new magento site.

Check Magento documentation of the import file format/process. (http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/data-csv-files.html)

You may try to use Magento 2 for a new magento site. The import/export feature is enhanced.

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do that but all my 3 sites are live and products being uploaded on daily or weakly basis, if i use CSV import method then i have to do it manually every-time any one of those site updated,

Comment: I was looking for something more automated process to archive that.

Comment: If you have Magento 2 EE, you have the module schedule import in order to plan recurrent import : http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/system/data-scheduled-import-export.html or you can buy community extension like https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html or you can try to create a module to handle the import with a cron.